# Ext JS: migrating geoExt to 4... Ext.tree.TreePanel.nodeTypes is undefined

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4, extjs3

I am migrating my Ext JS 3.3.1 application to Ext JS 4 (with compatability layer for now). I am running into trouble with geoExt. I get the following error:

```
Ext.tree.TreePanel.nodeTypes is undefined
```

on line 33 of the GeoExt.js file.

Does anyone know how to work through this issue? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Ext 3.3.0 at the bottom of `TreePanel.js` there's this line

```
Ext.tree.TreePanel.nodeTypes = {};
```

Perhaps try adding it before your line 33 of GeoExt.js